# Creating a list of references to object attributes

Tags: python, oop

The problem in the code is that **Vector.numerical_vector** is a list of copies of floats, but I need it to be list of references, so when Vector.vector[n].value is changed, Vector.numerical_vector[n] is changed to the same value as well.

Thanks for help in advance!

```
class Var:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.value = float(val)

    def __float__(self):
        return self.value


class Vector:
    def __init__(self, vector):
        self.vector = vector
        self.numerical_vector = [float(x) for x in vector]

vars = [Var(i) for i in range(5)]
vector = Vector(vars)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to employ a `property` for that.

```py
class Vector:
    def __init__(self, vector):
        self.vector = vector
    @property
    def numerical_vector(self):
        return [x.value for x in self.vector]
```

Now `vector.numerical_vector` will always be synchronized. A drawback of this method is that it is recomputed each time you access it, some it may not be adapted to your specific application.

If performance is an issue, you could add `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` methods to Vector as follows:

```py
class Vector:
    def __init__(self, vector):
        self.vector = vector
        self.numerical_vector = [float(x) for x in vector]
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return self.vector[i]
    def __setitem__(self, i, val):
        self.vector[i] = val
        self.numerical_vector[i] = float(val)
```

In that case, if you set `vector_instance[i]`, then `vector_instance.numerical_vector[i]` will be also modified. But if you want to modify `vector_instance.vector[i]` directly, then synchronicity will be broken.

Depending on the use case, you can use either of the two approaches. Both have limitations but I don't think much more can be done.

Comment: I actually never though of this, it will add some syntactic sugar, so I don't have to type `[float(x) for x in a_Vector_instance.numerical_vector]` every time, but the problem with efficiency is still there, I want to avoid recomputing `Vector.numerical_vector` every time I access it.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do that in python. What you could do is make `numerical_vector` an object that, when accessed, returns the `float` value of the corresponding `vector` item. Eg

```py
class VectorWrapper:
    def __init__(self, vector):
        self.vector = vector

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return float(self.vector[i])
```

and set `self.numerical_vector = VectorWrapper(self.vector)`

If you *have to* return a `float` representation when `self.numerical_vector[i]` is referenced,